# The tag [policy] is invisible

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

The tag [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy) still exists (currently 1,083 questions), you can find it under [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) and you can [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy) for [policy] and find the respective questions, but the tag itself is no longer visible.

This leads to strange effects like a question with seemingly no tags:

[image: Question without any tags (but actually tagged "policy"]

Or the list of questions tagged [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy):

[image: Questions tagged "policy" without showing the tag]

Comment: Note: the tag is visible when you "Edit" a Question.

Comment: This might be on purpose, i.e. new feature that hide certain problematic tags from view, added [meta-tag:support] tag as well.

Comment: Note that it's also invisible on SO Teams for [the *Business* tier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jnDv.png) (the one with Collectives and Articles), but not on [the Basic and Free tier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wTvf.png).

Comment: @AndrewT. some new form of tag sponsoring?

Comment: @yivi Thanks! I don't know how I could forget to add beautiful red freehand circles.

Comment: Glad you appreciate them. Mostly I edited because I found the original screen-shots hard to read, probably because of my advanced age.

Comment: Perhaps the design team misunderstood the sentence "The policy should not get in the way"

Comment: Ah, interesting! This is most definitely related to Articles: `policy` happens to be a reserved tag (alongside `announcement`, `how-to-guide` and `knowledge-article`). We deliberately remove it from the rendered list of article tags, but that should only happen on sites that have Articles enabled - and never on questions/answers. Will look into it!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This issue has now been fixed.

When dealing with [Articles](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/12/how-we-built-it-articles-feature-stack-overflow-teams/), some tags are reserved and rendered a bit differently. We call them "Article Types", which currently include [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy), [announcement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/announcement), [how-to-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/how-to-guide) and [knowledge-article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/knowledge-article). Our tag renderer was supposed to always remove article types from the list of tags *on articles*, but it was eagerly removing them from all posts. I have updated the tag rendering method, changes will be up with our next prod build.