# Tags reserved for Articles are still blocked on Basic Teams instances that don't have Articles

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, stack-overflow-for-teams

I'm a part of a Team (we're using the Basic version that doesn't have the Articles feature). we typically use the [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy) tag to indicate not just canonical posts about how our organization does things, but also for discussions around existing policy. We have 34 (previously 35, before I ran into this issue) questions tagged with this tag. We also have a tag wiki and usage guidance for it that's unique to our Team's organization.

I was editing an older Teams post of ours, tagged with the [policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy) tag, and I was blocked from completing the edit, with the message "The 'policy' tag is not allowed." Digging into Meta SO a bit, I noticed that a staff member [mentioned that there are four Articles-only tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/410809/11171084). Testing it out, I noticed that **all of these tags are blocked on Teams instances**. I asked one of my Team's admins to attempt to add that tag to the question I was editing, in the event that it was a permissions issue, and they were blocked from doing so as well. That Team admin is also a member of other teams in which they are an admin, and they were unable to add the tag to any post, meaning that this is a global-block on all Teams instances.

At least three of the four tags ([policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/policy), [how-to-guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/how-to-guide), [announcement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/announcement)) are tags that I would personally consider using in a Teams environment, making this quite the annoying bug to deal with when editing old posts tagged with one of those tags.

Could this be looked into and fixed?

Comment: Given that Teams have the Articles feature as well, it seems to be working as intended that you're unable to add an article-only tag to a question... (Technically, the article creation flow just has you choose the article type, which automatically marks the article with the corresponding tag in the system.) Or am I misunderstanding your bug report?

Comment: Even if that's all true, @V2Blast, why should the Articles feature be so opinionated that the tags it has arbitrarily chosen are blocked from ever being used on questions? That's not behavior anyone would expect, nor is it reasonable to impose that across the board. Why should admins not be able to choose the tags they want to use on their own Team based on what they think is clear and helpful to their users? More broadly, why do Articles and Collectives have to keep breaking things that used to work well?

Comment: @CodyGray: I mean, folks are welcome to make that feature request (if someone hasn't already); it just wouldn't be a bug. I just wanted to confirm whether there was actually a bug in this case, or if the system was behaving as intended.

Comment: We're just using the Basic version which doesn't have access to Articles, @V2Blast (I believe that starts at the Business tier or something like that?) Though I suppose I can understand how this would be difficult to dissemble between Teams that are of a specific tier that don't have access to Articles and ones that do, and the ability to block/unblock tags based on that... But I back what Cody said - We quite like our [policy] tag, thank you very much! ;)

Comment: @V2Blast In addition, it's a change in how the Team works without any real notice, consideration for existing content, or explanation. The only information we had was a small notice that said "The 'policy' tag is not allowed", which doesn't explain anything as to what's going on or why something that *used to work fine* is no longer working. If the restriction had been in place from the beginning, then teams would have established tags which work around it, but it's confusing to impose such a restriction years into using the Teams product (even if it was just limited to Teams with Articles).

Comment: @V2Blast In other words, yes, it's definitely a bug for the restriction to be there in Teams without Articles, but I *strongly* hope that SE did a *much* better job of communicating with Teams instances with access to Articles about the restriction. For instance, even something like showing "The 'policy' tag can only be used in Articles" would be better, even though that is more code than reusing what's displayed for a normal blocklist hit.

Comment: For example, it would have been good for there to have been an announcement to Teams owners/admins when the restriction on the use of these tags was created, as it can mean quite a bit of work for them in order to re-tag existing questions, which could be very significant. Ideally, it would be an *option* for Team admins to decide which, if any, tags are restricted to Articles, as how that particular Team uses Articles could be completely different from how SO envisions Articles being used.

Comment: Yeah, I agree that I hope this restriction was clearly communicated to Teams at the time it was implemented. (I don't think I was even working here at the time, though.) And yeah, I agree that it'd be nice if the message was more informative; I think that's just the base message shown for blocklisted tags (if no additional guidance is provided). If someone hasn't made a feature request for that already, it'd be worthwhile as well.

Comment: There's just no good technical reason why tags used by Articles need to be blocked from being used on questions... This is a pointless, arbitrary restriction. If a Teams admin wants to post an Article tagged [policy], and then allow questions about that [policy], that is a perfectly valid and reasonable use-case. It's not about improving the error message; it's about fixing the software so that it doesn't arbitrary block valid use-cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. It was a conscious decision when we released the Articles feature. Just in case, we have added this to our feature request tracker, but as of now, this will be classified as `bydesign`.